# Invalid Characters (Blank line) in String

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, replace, trim, findstr

I got the error "Invalid Characters in Path." My path is being output to a .txt file using the $findstr command and get deleted in the process of the application so I wrote a simple sub to output the string to a Textbox to see what was throwing the error.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Folder = Application.StartupPath & "\PRODUCTION"
    Dim MyFile As String = File.ReadAllText(Folder & "\results3.txt")
    MyFile.Replace("/n", "") ' One of my various attempts
    TextBox2.Text = Folder & "\" & MyFile & "<--END"
End Sub
```

An example of what is showing up:

```
C:/user/.../file.asasm
<--END
```

For some reason the findstr command is adding a second blank line after my path and I have so far been unable to remove it.  At the advice of several other threads on here I have tried:

```
MyFile.Trim() ' From MSDN is seems this only removes null spaces and not blank lines
MyFile.TrimEnd() ' Same result as trim
MyFile.Replace("/n","") ' I'm not sure if the /n parameter can be used in this way
MyFile.Replace(10,"") ' I thought this one for sure would work since 10 corresponds to a new line in the ASCII Table
```

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.  I realize there is several other threads on this topic, but none of the solutions seem to be working here.

REVISED:
The solution I implemented in my code was

```
MyFile = MyFile.Replace(Envirnment.NewLine,"")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
MyFile.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
```

Which on Windows should be the same as:

```
MyFile.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
```

Also try:

```
MyFile.Replace(vbCr, "")
```

or

```
MyFile.Replace(vbLf, "")
```

Depending on the type of newline you have, either should work for you.

**EDIT:** regarding why `MyFile.Replace(10,"")` did not work for you. You became a victim of implicit type conversion (a feature of VB.NET), so this line was executed as:

```
MyFile.Replace("10","")
```

Please make sure you have `Option Strict On`, if you want to avoid such issues.

Comment: I tried a few of these and I like the first solution the most.  It has the best readability for someone to find later on in my code.  Can you explain where implement 'Option Strict On'

Comment: @Matt: Depending on your project size, can be either on top of each file (as first statement), for gradual migration, or project-wide (`Project Properties -> Compile -> Option Strict On`). Also see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329).

Answer (score 2):

Trim will also work `MyFile = MyFile.Trim(vbNewLine.ToCharArray)`

Comment: An interesting usage example of Trim function. +1.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.NewLine` is probably the best way to refer to a newline. `"/n"` is definitely not. For one thing, you're surely thinking of `"\n"`, not `"/n"` - and for another, in vb.net even backslashes are interpreted literally (not as a control character).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've always wondered about that. And the / instead of \ was a typo